# phpseclib functions help needed

Tags: php, phpseclib

I want to calculate `ciphertext=m(pow)e mod(n)`

I saw this example in phpseclib:

```
<?php
include('Math/BigInteger.php');

$a = new Math_BigInteger(5);
$b = new Math_BigInteger(3);
$c = new Math_BigInteger(4);

echo $a->powMod($b, $c); // outputs 1 (eg. 125 % (4 * 31))
?>
```

Can anyone explain `echo $a->powMod($b, $c);`?

Answer (score 1):

From [the source code](http://phpseclib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/phpseclib/trunk/phpseclib/Math/BigInteger.php?revision=223&view=markup#l1535), `powMod` calls `modPow`, which says at the very top,

> ```
> * Performs modular exponentiation.
> ```

Wikipedia says that [modular exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) is:

> a type of exponentiation performed over a modulus. It is particularly useful in computer science, especially in the field of cryptography.  A "modular exponentiation" calculates the remainder when a positive integer `b` (the base) raised to the `e`-th power (the exponent), `b`<sup>`e`</sup>, is divided by a positive integer `m`, called the modulus. In symbols, this is, given base `b`, exponent `e`, and modulus `m`, the modular exponentiation `c` is: `c = b`<sup>`e`</sup>`(mod m)`
>
> For example, given `b = 5`, `e = 3`, and `m = 13`, the solution `c` is the remainder of dividing 5<sup>3</sup> by 13, which is the remainder of 125 / 13, or 8.

In other words, it is the correct function to use for the thing you are doing.

Which, by the way, is *insane*.  *Never* roll your own crypto.  **Never**.

Comment: ok thanks , and i also wants to know that whether i need any other extension to use these functions or can i just include the inbuilt files like include('Crypt/RSA.php'); in this example. for using these big ints or hexadecimal code?

Comment: As noted [in the documentation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/math/intro.html), it has it's own internal code to handle big numbers, but it can take advantage of installed extensions.  It will select to do so automatically.